# I find myself lost in this error message on hackerRank's function task

Tags: c++, function

the error message goes as follows:
Compilation error :(

Check the compiler output, fix the error and try again.

Compile Message

Solution.cpp: In function ‘int max_of_four(int, int, int, int)’:
Solution.cpp:22:1: error: control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type]
}
^
cc1plus: some warnings being treated as errors
Exit Status

1

I do not know what it means, on my Code::Blocks 20.03 everything goes smoothly, unfortunately, not on this site. Anybody knows what this error message refers to and potential fixes?

Thank you very much!

```
int max_of_four(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
if((a>=b)&&(a>=c)&&(a>=d)){
    return a;
  }
else if((b>=a)&&(b>=c)&&(b>=d)){
    return b;
  }
else if((c>=b)&&(c>=a)&&(c>=d)){
    return c;
  }
else if((d>=b)&&(d>=c)&&(d>=a)){
    return d;
  }
}
int main() {
    int a, b, c, d;
    scanf("%d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d);
    int ans = max_of_four(a, b, c, d);
    printf("%d", and);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message means that there is a `return` statement missing in `max_of_four` for the case that none of the conditions are true.

You need to add one, either in an unconditional final `else` part or simply at the end of the function.

If you are sure that you have already covered all possible cases, you could also remove the condition from the last `else if`.

Comment: Thank you very much, glad to have people like you around on this site!

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a default return to your int function, in case all of your conditions aren't met.
It is ususally a warning message but for you the warning message is treated as an error so you just have to add a return at the end of your function

Comment: Your the man bro, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If none of the `if` conditions is true, the control will reach the end of the function without hitting a `return`, which would cause undefined behavior (since the return type is not `void`).

While for you it might be obvious that at least one condition is always true, it's not as obvious for your compiler.

Since you know that if the first three conditions are false, the last one is always going to be true, you can just remove the last condition (replace `else if (...)` with just `else`).

Comment: Your explanation made it so much easier to understand it! It seems blackcats aren't as unlucky as it is rumored and only forsee glory in the future.